# Equivalent in C# of converting between two struct type in C++

Tags: c#, c++, struct, casting

I have to replicate some C++ in C#. More specifically I have to create the equivalent of converting between pinit_param to pinit_param_g. The definition of pinit_param and pinit_param_g are below.
C++:

```
typedef struct init_param {
        int     size;   
        HWND        hwnd;   
    }  init_param, *pinit_param;
typedef struct init_param_g {
        int     size;   
        HWND        hwnd;   
        GUID        appKey;
    }  init_param_g, *pinit_param_g;

extern "C" LIBRARY_API int __cdecl api_init(pinit_param param);
...
init_param_g paramg;
memset(&paramg, 0, sizeof(init_param_g));
paramg.size = sizeof(init_param_g);
paramg.hwnd = GetConsoleHwnd();//not relevant what implementation GetConsoleHwnd() has
paramg.applicationKey = APP_GUID;//not relevant what value APP_GUID has
api_init((pinit_param)&paramg);
```

What I've done in C#:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 4)]
        public struct init_param
        {
            public int size;               
            public IntPtr hwnd;
        }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 4)]
        public struct init_param_g
        {
            public int size;  
            public IntPtr hwnd;  
            public Guid appKey;
        }
[DllImport...]
public static extern Int32 api_init(ref init_param param);
.....
init_param_g paramg = new init_param_g();
paramg.size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(init_param_g));
paramg.hwnd = HWND;
paramg.appKey = APP_GUID;
var ret = api_init(ref (init_param)paramg);//error
.... or
init_param paramg = new init_param();
paramg.iSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(init_param));
paramg.hwnd = HWND;
var ret = api_init(ref paramg);//the code compiles but initialization is not complete
```

I've tried to make init_param_g to inherit from init_param but you can't do that in C#.
I've tried to convert using (init_param) in front of the variable or (ref init_param). Compile error both times.

Comment: The C++ code has undefined behavior if `api_init` actually accesses through the casted pointer. It is not possible to do this kind of reinterpretation in standard C++ even if the structs share a common initial sequence. (However, it will work on current compilers in practice.) If it wasn't for the `extern "C"` then this would be C anyway. It isn't really how C++ is written.

Comment: Is there any reason why you must cast them this way? If not, you could just create a conversion method to create an new struct object with the guid. Also, is there a reason to have two types here in the first place? Could you just make `appKey` nullable?

Comment: I'm with @FelixCastor, create an explicit cast from `init_param` to `init_param_g` and an implicit cast operator in the other direction

Comment: @Flydog57 I can't make an implicit cast from init_param_g to init_param in C#.

Comment: Why not? I'm not talking about just having it work, I'm talking about writing a cast: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators like @serg does below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to provide custom type cast operator (implicit or explicit as you like). The following example shows implicit operator

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 4)]
    public struct init_param
    {
        public int size;               
        public IntPtr hwnd;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, Pack = 4)]
    public struct init_param_g
    {
        public int size;  
        public IntPtr hwnd;  
        public Guid appKey;
        
        public static implicit operator init_param(init_param_g self)
        {
            return new init_param()
            {
                size =  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(init_param_g)),
                hwnd = self.hwnd,
            };
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
    init_param_g paramg = new init_param_g();
    paramg.size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(init_param_g));
    paramg.hwnd = HWND;
    paramg.appKey = APP_GUID;
    var tmp = (init_param)paramg;
    var ret = api_init(ref tmp);//ok
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I understand now better what @Flydog57 was reffering to. The problem with this approach is that the memory pointed to by tmp variable does not contain the guid. Isn't there a way to declare paramg as IntPtr and use some unsafe pointers for cast? I'm not very good at pointers in C# or Marshal operations.

Comment: You can definitely use `Marshal.StructureToPtr` to get unmanaged pointer to the struct and pass it as you want, but this will make a *copy* of the struct into unmanaged memory. So, this will not a full equivalent of your C++ code. I do not know how to pass pointer to the struct "in place" without copying it.

Comment: That's the function I need. I've tested and the following changes worked:
`
init_param_g paramg = new init_param_g();
paramg.size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(init_param_g));
paramg.hwnd = HWND;
paramg.appKey = APP_GUID;
IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(api_init_g)));
Marshal.StructureToPtr(paramg,ptr,false);
var ret = api_init(ptr);
......
public static extern Int32 api_init(IntPtr param);
`